# VBA Cell Copy Character Limit

Tags: excel, vba

Part of my VBA code involves copying and pasting a long string from one cell to the other. My code works fine until if there are too many characters in the source cell. After some tests, I think my code will generate an `runtime error 1004` if the number of characters in `Cell E16` is greater than 8000 (approximately). At this moment, I have a workaround approach which is to assign the source cell to an intermediate cell. If possible, may I know what is the cause of this issue? Do I need to split the content of my cell (E16) into more than 1 if it is really long?

#### This approach does not work if too many characters are in E16

```
Sheets(SN_Pound).Range("A10") = Sheets(SN_LV).Range("E16")
```

#### This approach works

```
CHR_LV_str = Sheets(SN_LV).Range("E16")
Sheets(SN_Pound).Range("A10") = CHR_LV_str
```

Comment: hmm .. same error for `Sheets(SN_Pound).Range("A10").Value2 = Sheets(SN_LV).Range("E16").Value2` ? The limit for "Length of formula contents 8,192 characters" but "Total number of characters that a cell can contain 32,767 characters" https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever is causing the error seems to be related to using the default property of the `Range` object.  If the property is explicitly specified, there is no error:

```
With Sheets(1)
    .Range("E16").Value = String$(30000, "x")
    Debug.Print Len(.Range("E16").Value)        'Prints 30000
'    .Range("A10") = Range("E16")               'Error 1004
    .Range("A10").Value = .Range("E16").Value   'No error
    Debug.Print Len(.Range("A10").Value)        'Prints 30000
    .Range("E16").Value = String$(60000, "x")
    Debug.Print Len(.Range("E16").Value)        'Prints 32767
End With
```

Note that per the link that @Slai mentioned in the comments the maximum cell text length is 32767, but it simply gets truncated.  There isn't an error thrown if you attempt to assign a longer string.

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually, adding `.value` solves the problem.

Comment: I'm unsure if you meant for the `Error 1004` line to omit the `.` before `Range` and instead implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet.Range` (it's still error 1004, if you add the period, FWIW), but it prompted me to add trailing parentheses and then compare `.Range("A10") = .Range("E16")() ` which is *Error 9 Subscript out of range*, and also to try `.Range("A10") = Range("E16")()` which is *no error*. So in addition to adding `.Value` and `[_Default]`, you can also add `()` depending upon how you reference `Range`  o.O